# Как выбрать следующий селектор jQuery в блоке при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Я новичок еще в javascript, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно выбрать селектор.
Допустим, есть блок с классом `.class`, в нем идет несколько ссылок `<a></a>`.
Есть кнопка `<button>`.
Первая ссылка активна.

**Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выбиралась одна следующая ссылка?**

Пробовал использовать `next()`, но тогда выбирались все следующие ссылки, а нужна одна.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var link = $('.class a').attr('href');
    var prevActive = $('.class a.active').attr('href');
    var next = ???
    $('.class a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(next).addClass('active');
    $(prevActive).fadeOut(25, function() {
        $(link).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Что подставить в переменную `next`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного переработал ваш код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var prevActive = $('.class').find('a.active');
        var next = prevActive.next('a'); // Выбираем следующую ссылку в блоке
        prevActive.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

А можно всё это дело написать и так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
       $('.class').find('a.active').removeClass('active')
                  .next('a').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[Пример обычный](http://jsfiddle.net/r26b0ozt/)

[Пример в одну строчку](http://jsfiddle.net/r26b0ozt/1/)

**UPD**.
По функциям `fadeOut()` и `fadeIn()`, вот такое [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/r26b0ozt/2/) сделал по текстам:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var prevActive = $('.class').find('a.active');
        var next = prevActive.next('a');
        $('.text').find('.text-block').fadeOut(25); // Скрывает все тексты, с нужным классом
        prevActive.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
        $('.class a').each(function(index) { // Перебирает все ссылки
            if($(this).hasClass('active')) { // Если находит ссылку с классом active
                $('.text').find('.text-block').eq(index).fadeIn(); // То показывает блок с классом .text-block, который стоит по счёту (переменная index) таким же как активная ссылка
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Не думаю, что моё решение идеально, можно решить интереснее, но по крайней мере в нём всё понятно выглядит.

**UPD2**. Зацикливание.

Пришлось переработать функцию, но [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/r26b0ozt/3/) мне нравится больше, чем предыдущий:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var length = $('.class a').length - 1; // вычисляем количество ссылок, начиная с 0
        $('.class a').each(function(index) {
            if($(this).hasClass('active') && index != length) { // Добавилась проверка на последний элемент
                $(this).removeClass('active')
                  .next('a').addClass('active'); // Манипуляции с ссылками
                $('.text').find('.text-block').fadeOut(25)
                          .eq(index+1).fadeIn(); // Манипуляции с текстами
                return false; // Нужно прекратить цикл, потому что следующая итерация снова найдёт активный элементе, мы ведь добавили активный класс следующему элементу
            } else if (index == length) { // Если элемент последний
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $('.class').find('a').first().addClass('active'); // Активируем первую ссылку
                $('.text').find('.text-block').fadeOut(25)
                          .eq(0).fadeIn(); // Показываем первый текст
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: fadeOut() и fadeIn() использовал, чтобы скрыть и показать блок с текстом. Делаю систему тестирования, в общем, при клике на кнопку нужно, чтобы скрывался текст из предыдущей ссылки и показывался из новой. Если поможете доделать скрипт, буду признателен.

Comment: @Rage, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Единственное хотелось бы еще, чтобы когда доходит до последней ссылки, при нажатии на кнопку переходит опять на первую.

Comment: @Rage, обновил ответ